# validation disappear after page refresh using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to apply validation in my `Sign Up` page on `email` field and below is the `Sign Up` page:

```
<%= form_for(@user,:html => {:id => "signup"}) do |f| %>
<table style="margin-left:30px;font-size:medium" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:15px">
        Email
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= f.text_field :email,:style => "font-size:medium", :id => "tf_email" %>
      </td>
      <td width="">
        <label for="validation_pw" id="errormessage1" visible="false" style="color:red; font-size:x-small;">
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
            <br/>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:left;">
            <%= f.submit "Login", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", :style => "font-size:12px;" %>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table
```

And below is the jquery validation function for email field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#signup").submit(function ( event ) {
    alert("Hassan");
    var email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var hasError = false;
    var inp_email = $("#tf_email").val();
    if(!email.test(inp_email))
    {
      var message = $("#errormessage1").html("Enter your email address");
      message.show();
      hasError = true; 
    }
    else
    {
      hasError = false;
      $("#errormessage1").empty().hide();
    }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Its working fine and shows validation but it disappear after page refresh and not stable on the page whenever I put the valid email address.
Kindly suggest me, waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: On submit it is coming and if you refresh the page again, it is not being shown, right? That is how it should behave, why you need it to validate the fields on page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to use return true or false after checking your email field, 
Also remove an extra closing brace, which is not opened

```
$("#signup").submit(function ( event ) {
    .....
    if(!email.test(inp_email))
    {
        var message = $("#errormessage1").html("Enter your email address");
        message.show();
        hasError = true; 
    }
    else
    {
        hasError = false;
        $("#errormessage1").empty().hide();
    }
    return ! hasError;// used !, if valid then true else return false;
    //} remove it it is an extra brace, which is not opened
});
```

And if you want to show error on refreshing the page then try to use localStorage for your validation and on page load check if localstorage has some error value then validate your form again like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkValidity(){
        alert("Hassan");
        var email = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        var hasError = false;
        var inp_email = $("#tf_email").val();
        if(!email.test(inp_email) || (localStorage.getItem('hasError') && localStorage.getItem('hasError')==true))
        {
           var message = $("#errormessage1").html("Enter your email address");
           message.show();
           hasError = true; 
           localStorage.setItem('hasError',true);
        }
        else
        {
           hasError = false;
           localStorage.setItem('hasError',false);
           $("#errormessage1").empty().hide();
        }
    }
    $(function(){
       $("#signup").submit(function ( event ) {
          checkValidity();
       });
       checkValidity();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on submit, it will try to post the respective form to server and reload the page.

You have to use either

```
event.preventDefault();
```

or

```
return false;
```

When you want to show error message.